# CASE WHEN NULL query

Tags: sql-server, null, case

I have the folowing existing query:

```
SELECT SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21
  FROM [DATABASE] 
  WHERE [Posting Date] = '2014-06-22' 
  AND [Location Code] = '129'
```

Sometimes the result is NULL, so I want to edit the query and result '0' if the result is NULL else show the normal result.

I've figured out I should use CASE and ISNULL or IS NULL, but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21
    IS NULL '0' 
    ELSE SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21
    END FROM [DATABASE] 
    WHERE [Posting Date] = '2015-07-01' AND [Location Code] = '121'
```

I receive the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '0'.

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a **THEN**: `WHEN SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21 IS NULL THEN '0'`

Comment: could you pls edit the tags to specify the SQL engine ? (SQL Server, Oracle... ?)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've got some product specific answers below...)

Comment: When using `CASE` remember the dichotomy between simple ( `CASE <expr_test:T> WHEN <expr1_val:T> THEN <expr1_return:U> ...  WHEN <expr<n>_val:T> THEN <expr<n>_return:U> ELSE  <expr_return_dflt:U> END` ) and searched ( `CASE WHEN <expr1_test:BOOLEAN> THEN <expr1_return:U> ...  WHEN <expr<n>_test:BOOLEAN> THEN <expr<n>_return:U> ELSE  <expr_return_dflt:U>`) case statements to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21, 0) Result
  FROM [TABLE] 
  WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong syntax. I prefer you to use `COALESCE` (ANSI standard) instead of `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21, 0) 
FROM [Table] 
WHERE [Posting Date] = '2015-07-01' AND [Location Code] = '121'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Use `THEN` after condition:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21
IS NULL THEN '0' 
ELSE SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21
END FROM [DATABASE] 
WHERE [Posting Date] = '2015-07-01' AND [Location Code] = '121'
```

**Better Solution:**

Using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21,0)
FROM [DATABASE] 
WHERE [Posting Date] = '2015-07-01' 
  AND [Location Code] = '121'
```

`COALESCE` will return the first parameter which is not null

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL([Sales Amount (Actual)],0)) * 1.21
  FROM [DATABASE] 
  WHERE [Posting Date] = '2014-06-22' 
  AND [Location Code] = '129'
```